# Segfault when assigning to struct within 2d array through function call

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, implicit-conversion

I have the following `typedef`:

```
typedef struct cell_t {
    int x; // x coord of this cell                                                                                 
    int y; // y coord of this cell                                                                                 
    int neighbour_count; // Size of the following array                                                            
    struct cell_t **neighbours; // array of pointers to neighbours                                                 
} cell_t;
```

and some code to initialize this type (`neighbour_count` and `neighbours` are to be set later)

```
cell_t *create_cell(int x, int y){
    cell_t *cell = malloc(sizeof(cell_t));
    cell->x = x;
    cell->y = y;

    return cell;
}
```

I have `myfun` to initialize the `neighbours` and `neighbour_count` variables for a matrix of `cell_t`, which it reads from some external source.

```
int myfun(cell_t ***cells, int width, int height){
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            // Read data from source, including the long `list_size`

            cells[x][y]->neighbour_count = (int) list_size; // This segfaults
        }
    }
}
```

So in my `main`, I have the following:

```
int width = 3, height = 3;

cell_t *cells[width][height];

for (int x = 0; x < width; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
        cells[x][y] = create_cell(x,y);
    }
}

myfun(cells, width, height);
```

When setting the neighbour count, it segfaults (as marked in the third block of code).

What I think I'm doing is that in my `main` I initialize an empty matrix of pointers to cell objects, and then loop through width and height, creating cells, and storing the pointers to them in the matrix. Then in `myfun`, I'm simply accessing a the variable neighbour_count of these cells and setting it. But apparently I'm mistaken, as it segfaults (not always on the first loop though, but generally quite quickly).

I'm thinking perhaps I did something wrong such that the matrix `cells` does not actually contain pointers to `cell_t` structs. But I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

I am getting a warning that "passing argument 1 of ‘myfun’ from incompatible pointer type", and that it should instead be of type `cell_t * (*)[(sizetype)(height)]`; perhaps that helps? I would expect there not to be a problem, as `struct_t ***` should be good for a 2d array of pointers, no?

Comment: What are initial values for x,y in your for loops? `int x; x < width; x++`

Comment: @rafix07 well spotted, I fixed those lines now (but the problem remains)

Comment: `cell_t *cells[width][height];` is not compatible with `cell_t ***cells` and your compiler should tell you as much. Furthermore you don't seem to allocate memory for `neighbours` anywhere. Consider [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) instead.

Comment: The memory allocation for neighbours isn't in this code because it segfaults before that anyway. But why are these types not compatible? Seems to me that a pointer to `cell_t` should be `cell_t *`, and an array of such things `cell_t **` and a 2D array of such things `cell_t ***`. Perhaps this is the mistake I'm making?

Comment: A pointer is not an array. A pointer to pointer is not a 2D array. Nor can it point to a 2D array. It's all explained in the link I gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the first function parameter

```
int myfun(cell_t ***cells, int width, int height){
```

and the type of the supplied argument

```
myfun(cells, width, height);
```

do not correspond each other. The function argument declared like

```
cell_t *cells[width][height];
```

is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. That is it has the type `cell_t * ( * )[height]`.

Thus the corresponding function should be declared like

```
int myfun( int width, int height, cell_t * cells[][height] ){
```

or like

```
int myfun( int width, int height, cell_t * ( *cells )[height] ){
```

that declares the same function.

Comment: @Wysaard I have not understood your question. I showed you how the function shell be declared. What is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I was being stupid, your solution seems to work; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One thing is not correct in your code that i recognize is the definition of pointer.

```
cell_t *cells[width][height];
```

This defifnition is not for pointer that points to an array 2D. Like @Lundin commented above, it is not compatible with `cell_t ***cells`. If you want to define a pointer that points to an array 2D, you can use the code below:

```
cell_t cells[width][height];
cell_t *ptr = &cells;
```

The pointer `ptr` is compatible with `***cells` in your code

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is that `cells` is a 2D array of pointers, namely pointers to `cell_t`s. How would I go about doing that? I assumed `cell_t cells[width][height]` would be a 2D array of `cell_t`, so `cell_t *cells[width][height]` would be a 2d array of pointers to `cell_t`.